# How to run a test suite with module and class name as a variable?

Tags: python, python-unittest

I am wondering if it is possible to run a test suite like this way:

```
suite1 = suite_loader.loadTestsFromTestCase(test_gtm_{}.{}TagManager)
suite2 = suite_loader.loadTestsFromTestCase(test_links_{}.{}Links)
```

So the specific test would run based on the user input.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is in general in python to run functions/tests as strings/vars.

Answer from - [Calling a function of a module by using its name (a string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-of-a-module-by-using-its-name-a-string)

```
from foo import bar

module = __import__('foo')
file = getattr(module, 'test_{}'.format(some_var))
run = getattr(file, '{}'.format(some_other_var))
```

And then this will work:

```
suite1 = suite_loader.loadTestsFromTestCase(run)
```